# Plot legend issue

Tags: r, plot

When I use the following code, I can only see the boundary lines for the legend; nothing shows up inside!

```
xx <- c(-0.53,0.53)   
yy <- c(1.7024,1.9147)   
leg <- c(-0.53,1.7289)  
x <- c(-0.53,0.53)  
y1 <- c(1.8242,1.8085)
y2 <- c(1.9147,1.7378)
plot(xx,yy,type='n',font=2,font.lab=2,xlab='x1',ylab='Y',main='Interaction')
lines(x,y1,lwd=3,lty=1,col=1)
lines(x,y2,lwd=3,lty=5,col=1)
points(x,y1,col=1,pch=16)
points(x,y2,col=1,pch=16)
legend(leg[1],leg[2],legend=c('X2(1)','X2(2)'),lwd=c(3,3),lty=c(1,5),col=c(1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this plot with your code. Do you expect something else?

[image]

version.string R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)

Comment: this is what I'm looking for; this may be due to an error with my RStudio...

Comment: I get [some clipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpbkK.png) on with my default settings too.